Dense span of eigenvectors and spectrum of unbounded operators
Let $ H $ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space, and let $ T $ be an unbounded linear operator on $ H $. Assume that $ T $ is densely defined and closed.
It is well known that if $ T $ has a compact resolvent, then the spectrum of $ T $ consists entirely of discrete spectrum.
The converse, however, is less clear. Suppose $ T $ has sufficiently "nice" eigenvalues, meaning these eigenvalues are isolated points in $ \mathbb{C} $, their corresponding eigenspaces are finite-dimensional, and the linear span of the associated eigenvectors is dense in $ H $. What can we say about the rest of the spectrum? Can continuous spectrum or residual spectrum still be present? Could you provide an illustrative example?
Note that $ T $ is not necessarily self-adjoint, making approximation by spectral projections challenging. Additionally, I am particularly interested in the case where $ T $ is maximally dissipative, i.e., $ T $ generates a $ C_0 $ contraction semigroup on $ H $. I am uncertain whether maximal dissipativity would exclude other types of spectrum.

Let $H = \oplus_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{C}^2$ and $T = \oplus_{n \geq 1} \begin{pmatrix} 2n - 1 & n^3 \\ 0 & 2n \end{pmatrix}$. Then $T$ satisfies the required conditions: $T$ has point spectrum the set of positive integers, each eigenspace has dimension $1$, and the span of all eigenvectors is the space of all finitely supported sequences in $H = \oplus_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{C}^2$, which is dense in $H$. But $T$ has spectrum $\mathbb{C}$ - think about the inverse of $T - \lambda$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, it will always be unbounded. In fact, $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is exactly the continuous spectrum of $T$.
